Why do my radio buttons change appearance when hovered over?
I'm using Python 3.11.10 with Spyder 6.0.2.
I don't know if this is a coding issue, or if it's something to do with the Spyder 6.0.2 platform I'm using, or a glitch in this version of Python, or what it might be. When I run the app, the radio buttons change appearance when I hover over them, even though I don't have any sort of hover code written. If I select one of the options, the whole group goes back to the desired appearance, and it no longer changes the unselected radio buttons in the same group when hovering. It only happens when there's no option selected (in the initialized state of the buttons, which is with no option selected). It's a glitch of some sort, and I can't find anything on the internet to explain why this might be happening.
The code for some of the radio buttons is here:
drivewheelbut = tkinter.IntVar(value=0)
drivewheel1 = tkinter.Radiobutton(master=cstfrm, variable=drivewheelbut, value=1, bg="#b2b4b7", takefocus=False)
drivewheel1.place(height=20, x=502, y=450)
drivewheel1.configure(bg="#292d2e")
drivewheel2 = tkinter.Radiobutton(master=cstfrm, variable=drivewheelbut, value=2, bg="#b2b4b7", takefocus=False)
drivewheel2.place(height=20, x=502, y=470)
drivewheel2.configure(bg="#292d2e")
drivewheel3 = tkinter.Radiobutton(master=cstfrm, variable=drivewheelbut, value=3, bg="#b2b4b7", takefocus=False)
drivewheel3.place(height=20, x=502, y=490)
drivewheel3.configure(bg="#292d2e")
drivewheel4 = tkinter.Radiobutton(master=cstfrm, variable=drivewheelbut, value=4, bg="#b2b4b7", takefocus=False)
drivewheel4.place(height=20, x=502, y=510)
drivewheel4.configure(bg="#292d2e")
drivewheellbl1 = tkinter.Label(master=cstfrm, text="FWD", bg="#292d2e", fg="#b2b4b7")
drivewheellbl1.place(x=522, y=450)
drivewheellbl2 = tkinter.Label(master=cstfrm, text="RWD", bg="#292d2e", fg="#b2b4b7")
drivewheellbl2.place(x=522, y=470)
drivewheellbl3 = tkinter.Label(master=cstfrm, text="AWD", bg="#292d2e", fg="#b2b4b7")
drivewheellbl3.place(x=522, y=490)
drivewheellbl4 = tkinter.Label(master=cstfrm, text="4WD", bg="#292d2e", fg="#b2b4b7")
drivewheellbl4.place(x=522, y=510)

All the others are designed the same.


I did notice that this phenomenon only happens in the groups of four radio buttons. The group of two buttons (Automatic or Manual) don't do this (even though they are written exactly the same). It's only the two larger groupings of four radio buttons.
Any ideas what might be causing this?

It looks similar to this and this.

Please post a [mre]. The problem might (that is even very likely I would say) be the one of the post @8349697 've shown. But we can't tell, because from your code, we don't know what happens to drivewheelbut. Besides, even knowing that it is the problem, the workaround differ from the context. It could be to use global. It could be to what drivewheelbut an attribute of a function. Or an attribute of a class. Or to return it. Or...

Bossman, you're looking at the reproducible example. There's nothing more to the code. I created radio buttons and an IntVar() to go with them. And this is what they do when you pass the mouse pointer over them. I've haven't yet even created functions to go with them. But I do intend to give the information from the linked examples a try and see if it does the trick. I will let everyone know if it does when I have the free time to get it written.

@AFrazier No, you are not providing a [mre].  What is cstfrm? Is the posted code inside a normal function or a class method? All of these are not clear.

@acw1668, that's the master. Some use root. That it says "master=" should clue you in to the fact that this is where the widget is located. Outside of that, the code given shows the creation of the relevant radio buttons and their associated IntVar(). Making the variable global did the trick, so don't worry about it. Problem is solved, thanks to the first person who messaged with an actual answer.

As shown in the comment links to the question, one of the solutions mentioned making the variable global. However, it didn't need to be in the function as the linked post suggested. A single line of code to make the variable global was all that was needed. The addition of global drivewheelbut prior to establishing drivewheelbut = tkinter.IntVar(value=0) did the trick.
global drivewheelbut
drivewheelbut = tkinter.IntVar(value=0)
drivewheel1 = tkinter.Radiobutton(master=cstfrm, variable=drivewheelbut, value=1, bg="#292d2e", takefocus=False)
drivewheel1.place(height=20, x=502, y=450)

